# call schedule function from client side

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to change the view from month to agenda in primefaces schedule component from a js function in my xhtml. Is this possible?
I tried the following code but it not works

```
function moveToDay(date){
 var toDate = new Date(date);
 alert(toDate);
 $('#schedule').fullCalendar( 'changeView', 'agendaDay' );
 $('#schedule').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', toDate );
}
```

Here 'schedule' is the id of p:schedule component, should i change this to #calendar in function?
any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your schedule widgetVar is `scheduleWV`.

```
 <p:schedule widgetVar="scheduleWV" >
```

As Pirmefaces generates the fullCalendar it adds an outer div form the original div of the fullCalendar jQuery object, taking that in consider your function would be like this.

```
function moveToDay(date){
   //fullCalendar is the first child of the component 
   myFullCal = PF('scheduleWV').jq.children(":first");

   var toDate = new Date(date);
   myFullCal.fullCalendar( 'changeView', 'agendaDay' );
   myFullCal.fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', toDate );
}
```

Hope this helps.